# How to add custom script to the particular Product Category page

Tags: categories, javascript, actions

I am trying to add the script to the particular Product Category page, but the code is not adding it to the category.

**Page (working):**

```
function wpb_hook_faq_javascript() {
  if (is_single ('8') || is_page ('8')) { 
    ?>
    <script type="application/ld+json">

    </script>

 <?php }
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'wpb_hook_faq_javascript');
```

**Product Category (not working):**

```
function wpb_hook_faqtocategory_javascript() {
  if ( in_category( 'category-name' )) { 
    ?>
    <script type="application/ld+json">

    </script>

 <?php }
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'wpb_hook_faqtocategory_javascript');
```

But the above code is not working.

**Product Category URL:**

```
wp-admin/term.php?taxonomy=product_cat&tag_ID=9&post_type=product
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`in_category()` should be used inside The Loop (unless if you pass a post ID as the second parameter like `in_category( 1, 1 )`) and only for the default/built-in `category` taxonomy.

For custom taxonomies like the `product_cat` in your case, you should use [`has_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/); however, if you're checking if the current request/page is a taxonomy archive page, you should instead use [`is_tax()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_tax/):

```php
function wpb_hook_faqtocategory_javascript() {
    if ( is_tax( 'product_cat', 9 ) ) { // 9 is the term ID, but you can use the slug/name
        ?>
        <script type="application/ld+json">

        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Or in WooCommerce (you're using WooCommerce, right?), you can use `is_product_category()`, but you'll need to know the term *slug*:

```php
function wpb_hook_faqtocategory_javascript() {
    if ( is_product_category( 'term-slug' ) ) {
        // ... your code here ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Rahul Kumar, you should mark this answer as correct if it worked for you.

Comment: @TonyDjukic. Done. I have marked it.

Comment: Thanks, @TonyDjukic and Rahul. :)